# Remove label tooltip for plotly from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, hover, plotly

I'm trying to use ggplotly to convert a ggplot while having different fields for the labels next to each point and on hover text box. When I try to set this explicitly in my ggplot, the label somehow also has a tooltip which is unwanted.

For example, if my ggplot is coded by this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(randomData, 
    aes(d30cumarpu, d30mult, col=cumarpu_mult_cluster, label=ip_country,
    text=paste('Country:', ip_country, '<br>',
               'd30cumarpu:', format(d30cumarpu, digits=2), '<br>',
               'd30mult:', format(d30mult, digits=2)))) +
    xlim(range(randomData[,'d30cumarpu'])[1]-2, range(randomData[,'d30cumarpu'])[2]) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes(x=d30cumarpu - 1.25), show.legend = FALSE) +
    labs(title = paste('ip_country',  'Clusters', sep = ' '))
```

then it will produce this image as desired.

[image]

However, when I transition this to plotly with

```
plotly1 <- ggplotly(p1, tooltip=c('text'))
```

I get the same graph except the label now has a hover tooltip in addition to the point as shown when using "compare data on hover".

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of the hover tooltip for the label?

I've been able to build the same thing using just plot_ly and setting hoverinfo='none' for my added text, but I can't figure out how to do that for ggplot converting to plotly.

```
plotly1 <- plot_ly(finaldata, x = ~d30cumarpu, y = ~d30mult, color=~cumarpu_mult_cluster, 
    text=~paste('Country:', ip_country, '<br>',
                'd30cumarpu:', format(d30cumarpu, digits=3), '<br>',
                'd30mult:', format(d30mult, digits=3)),
    hoverinfo='text') %>%
    add_markers() %>%
    add_text(x = ~d30cumarpu-1,
             y = ~d30mult,
             text = ~ip_country,
             color=~cumarpu_mult_cluster,
             hoverinfo='none',
             showlegend=FALSE)
```

[image]

Here's a sample of randomly generated and clustered data if anyone wants to play around:

```
> dput(randomData)
structure(list(ip_country = structure(c(215L, 107L, 73L, 179L, 
37L, 71L, 55L, 103L, 209L, 181L, 13L, 223L, 148L, 203L, 99L, 
31L, 95L, 100L, 211L, 166L, 113L, 156L, 64L, 149L, 57L, 42L, 
97L, 20L, 186L, 63L, 185L, 90L, 3L, 213L, 114L, 110L, 168L, 12L, 
160L, 54L, 157L, 94L, 177L, 118L, 116L, 167L, 45L, 106L, 85L, 
230L), .Label = c("??", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", 
"AO", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AW", "AX", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", 
"BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BQ", 
"BR", "BS", "BT", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CF", "CG", 
"CH", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CV", "CW", "CX", 
"CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", 
"ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", 
"GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GQ", "GR", 
"GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", 
"IL", "IM", "IN", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", 
"KE", "KG", "KH", "KM", "KN", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", 
"LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", 
"MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", 
"MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", 
"NC", "NE", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NZ", "OM", "PA", 
"PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", 
"PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", 
"SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SR", "SS", "ST", 
"SV", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TD", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TL", "TM", 
"TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "US", "UY", "UZ", 
"VA", "VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WF", "WS", "XK", "YE", 
"YT", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"), class = "factor"), cumarpu_mult_cluster = c("Tier 2", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 3", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 3", "Tier 1", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 1", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 2", "Tier 1", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", "Tier 1", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 3", "Tier 2", "Tier 3", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 1", "Tier 2", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", 
"Tier 3", "Tier 1", "Tier 2", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 2"
), d30cumarpu = c(107.930131712991, 105.222512638255, 117.462222411898, 
87.2866387698602, 121.973895325548, 104.33130777092, 84.2980036951461, 
90.6509433292393, 100.634933452598, 99.9760666381899, 77.2321875975337, 
107.574122251255, 94.5159444597197, 101.725494778504, 105.628530677554, 
115.118179594377, 106.590251691644, 111.220280746746, 92.1535863085354, 
95.7430771118969, 103.929975913722, 100.367571298246, 89.6791633877171, 
87.3513852861858, 97.7303471477638, 107.45589304708, 103.328191803325, 
88.7595954264223, 92.9386921777103, 92.7245613539153, 81.6568561472558, 
95.9231205973952, 100.268611947988, 109.116286375609, 116.343464755087, 
100.606856143597, 118.475725278658, 100.801249546513, 114.185558829789, 
114.586159354469, 100.558773396012, 84.8275942303004, 99.5142078508797, 
97.8564336084652, 120.958181976138, 102.023229068152, 105.177237108215, 
116.781432058498, 103.852448050474, 87.1811277597501), d30mult = c(94.1784926403024, 
117.741186943482, 97.8932802054684, 96.4789309381206, 105.851723262244, 
110.136846977567, 99.7743057140667, 90.9684514320939, 109.077729534112, 
111.61942897035, 95.420466027981, 109.279566678046, 78.9706486359243, 
83.2283288606423, 117.656557686126, 107.944474212631, 95.1613044154245, 
119.283591488307, 96.1588380493214, 84.1332253212426, 102.143017063566, 
88.6171827803067, 104.894135074642, 82.4736323889036, 105.010170995538, 
100.867562053473, 101.910735336673, 108.318390254185, 93.2096763159969, 
102.95862295423, 111.121658595741, 103.625898970539, 97.2908492702806, 
98.0305434605323, 100.669545180646, 91.3219833174809, 96.3799435914652, 
88.6044983529687, 91.8462867022671, 113.102456329798, 97.4163905941743, 
106.062648944944, 103.134482165704, 100.536030819785, 111.28253787677, 
94.4186654082415, 115.359589458142, 99.3755364766521, 100.215752153621, 
79.1017256181289)), .Names = c("ip_country", "cumarpu_mult_cluster", 
"d30cumarpu", "d30mult"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(421L, 
209L, 142L, 351L, 73L, 138L, 107L, 201L, 409L, 355L, 26L, 436L, 
290L, 397L, 193L, 61L, 185L, 195L, 413L, 325L, 221L, 306L, 125L, 
292L, 111L, 81L, 189L, 40L, 364L, 123L, 362L, 175L, 6L, 417L, 
223L, 215L, 329L, 24L, 313L, 105L, 308L, 183L, 347L, 231L, 227L, 
327L, 87L, 207L, 166L, 449L))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I was able to dig into the plotly structure and turn hoverinfo to none by finding which points in my list corresponded to the labels and eventually solved it with

```
for(i in 4:6){
    plotly1$x$data[[i]]$hoverinfo = 'none'
}
```

However, this doesn't seem sustainable, so if there are any other methods out there, I would love to hear them!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable the hoverinfo separately as [@jtanman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2150510/jtanman) shows, however there are other options available too!

The first, and most likely best, is setting the tooltip argument to `NULL`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

DT <- data.table(mtcars)

p <- ggplot(DT, aes(x = mpg, y = hp))
p=p+ geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = disp), fill = '#FFFFFF', shape = 21L, stroke = 0.4, alpha = 0.5)

ggplotly(p, tooltip = NULL)
```

This works for most ggplot functions but not all.. An example is `stat_density` as the contours themself have hoverInfo so `ggplotly` crashes. An approach for this would be to let ggplotly create the hover, and delete it afterwards. This is of course less optimal than skipping the hoverInfo entirely. The code for removing the tooltip would be:

```
p <- ggplot(DT, aes(x = mpg, y = hp))
p=p+ stat_density2d(aes(fill = factor(cyl), alpha = after_stat(level)), geom = 'polygon', adjust = c(2L, 2L), contour_var = 'ndensity')
p=p+ geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = disp), fill = '#FFFFFF', shape = 21L, stroke = 0.4, alpha = 0.5)

ggplotly(p) %>% style(hoverinfo = 'none')
```